# css floating column header

Tags: html, css

I hava a simple question about css.
In my project i have a long width table. Like this:

[image]

Like you see the bottom scroll is nesesery.
The forecast is the header for this month under him.
On second screen you see the situation when i scroll to the end.[image: On second screen you see the situation when i scroll to the end.]

Right now the forecast text is in the center of cell.
So when this cell will be much longer the forecast text will be visible only when i scrool to center. My question is: Is it possible to make this text visible always when i scroolin on the forecast section and its float with the scrool ?

Comment: Only way to position an element based on the displayed viewport instead of the document flow I can think of is `position: fixed`. At least if you're looking for a CSS solution not a JavaScript one.

Comment: I would rather look for a JavaScript solution where you know the scrollbar position. This is more stable and feels less `hacky` than a weird CSS positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution you can create an absolute positioned layer with transparent background.

Look a snippet as an example:

```css
.div1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y:  hidden;
    background-color: green;
    color: yellow;
}
.div2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: green;
    top: 30px;
}
.hdr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="hdr">HEADER</div> 
    <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis fringilla tellus. Pellentesque porttitor elit sit amet arcu efficitur, vel ultricies lacus posuere. Etiam sed quam quis 
tellus accumsan vehicula quis a enim.
 Donec volutpat, justo ut tempor facilisis, dui erat semper leo, vel facilisis libero arcu quis est. Mauris dapibus hendrerit porta. Sed non nisi libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam rhoncus, metus vel 
ultrices scelerisque, magna felis dignissim tellus, in suscipit neque diam eu libero. Fusce accumsan fringilla libero, ut auctor odio maximus vel.
Aenean a venenatis leo, elementum varius enim. Donec vitae turpis sit amet magna aliquet pulvinar nec eget odio. Ut vitae ornare augue.
Sed iaculis enim at scelerisque suscipit. Cras at tortor congue, vestibulum ipsum a, viverra lectus. Cras massa neque, commodo sed lacus id, convallis sodales urna</div>
  </div>
```